# Any trick to swap order of determinant and matrix inverse operation?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, matrix, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Been thinking through fitting a kind of Gaussian mixture model in more of a neural network style (kind of similar to RNADE or RMADE by Larochelle, without going into details) and see that this could scale really nicely to very large dimensions if I could avoid having to know both $\Sigma$ AND $\Sigma^{-1}$ per the multivariate Gaussian equation.  I.e., from what I'm seeing, the Gaussian PDF...

$det(2\pi\Sigma)^{-\frac12}e^{-\frac12(x-\mu)^t \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$

seems to require both the covariance and precision matrices.   I bet the answer is no, but is there a way I could fit parameters for the precision matrix and avoid having to invert it to get the normalization constant (e.g., if i could swap the order of the determinant and inverse sqrt operation, and just need the $\Sigma^{-\frac12}$, I could do a Cholesky decomposition on the precision matrix).

Comment: Are you looking for $det(A^{-1})=det(A)^{-1}$?

Comment: ya so that is a legit property?  Like the transpose of the inverse is the inverse of the transpose?

Comment: Well yes. More generally det(AB) = det(A) det(B). It's very surprising that you know very advanced stuff like Cholesky decomposition but you have doubts about this fact!

Comment: Well....guess this is the first time I've needed to know it :-)